# Conversion of lat/lng to x/y on a Gall stereographic world map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a world map in Gall stereographic projection, identical to the map here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall_stereographic_projection

I'm trying to convert lat/lng to x/y using the formulae from the wiki:

```js
function latLngToGallXY(lat: number, lng: number): { x: number; y: number } {
  const mapWidth = 1024
  const R = mapWidth / (2 * Math.PI)

  // Convert latitude and longitude from degrees to radians for the trigonometric functions.
  const latRad = (lat * Math.PI) / 180
  const lngRad = (lng * Math.PI) / 180

  // Apply the Gall stereographic projection formulae.
  const x = R * lngRad + 512
  const y = -1 * 2 * R * Math.tan(latRad / 2) + 512

  return { x, y }
}
```

When I transform 0/0, 10/10 ... 80/80 to x/y, I get the following result:

[image]

X is being calculated correctly, while Y grows approx. 20% slower than it should. I tried with the other formula from the wiki, no luck. ChatGPT wasn't able to fix it either.

Here the map given as an example from the wiki, overlayed on top of my map. As you can see, the projection is identical, so the problem must be in the math.

[image]

EDIT: These are the first set of formulae from the wiki article, neither X nor Y works:

```
const x = (R * lngRad) / Math.sqrt(2) + 512
const y = -1 * R * (1 + Math.sqrt(2) / 2) * Math.tan(latRad / 2) + 512
```

EDIT2: Had to multiply Y by Math.sqrt(2) for some reason. Here are the final formulae after simplification:

```
const mapWidth = 1024
const R = mapWidth / (2 * Math.PI)

const latRad = lat * (Math.PI / 180)
const lngRad = lng * (Math.PI / 180)

const x = R * lngRad + 512
const y = -R * (Math.sqrt(2) + 1) * Math.tan(latRad / 2) + 512
```

Comment: You aren't dividing by sqrt2 for the x? What is the +512 for and why is lng -= 10? I also don't see 1 + sqrt 2 / 2 anywhere in the code...

Comment: lng -= 10 is necessary because my map is 10 deg offset to west. It's irrelevant to the Y calculation. +512 is an offset to start from the center of the map, rather than the top left. If you look at the wiki article, I'm using the second set of formulas. Tried the first, didn't work.

Comment: Added the first set of formulae that I tried to my question

Comment: I don't know why but multiplying Y by sqrt2 fixed it. Will update my question with the final formulae.